# How to pick data from multiple db tables and inserting into one table using php and html button element

Tags: php, mysqli

**So the idea of the code below is to pick values from different db tables, which are then passed to a single db table using a html button in (approvals.php) to pass the parameter set in the code below in(accept.php).**

```
$connect =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projectii");
$query = "SELECT * FROM permits, sanitarypermits, mechanicalpermits, electricalpermits, 
plumbingpermits, electronicspermit
WHERE
  permits.Id = sanitarypermits.Id = mechanicalpermits.Id = electricalpermits.Id = plumbingpermits.Id 
= electronicspermit.Id ";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){

$query = "INSERT INTO approved_permits
      SELECT * FROM permits WHERE permits.Id
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM sanitarypermits WHERE sanitarypermits.Id
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM mechanicalpermits WHERE mechanicalpermits.Id
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM electricalpermits WHERE electricalpermits.Id
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM plumbingpermits WHERE plumbingpermits.Id
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM mechanicalpermits WHERE electronicspermit.Id ";
    }
    else{
      echo "There is an unknown problem";
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: `Union` work only when all corresponding columns have the same structure and the same index. Eg:  `return T1-int, return T2-string` on `first return_column`, Cannot do `UNION`. Same in your case Union result columns from  your table assume return different columns types.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM permits WHERE permits.Id` ... maybe it should be continue with `=something` ...

Comment: And what's your quesiton about all that code?

Comment: The statement at the top is the question. I'm trying to figure that out